# Get page name from URL-encoded page name in MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

Is there any *built in function* to get the page name from the page title in MediaWiki. Example: I have `Main_Page` and I want `Main Page`.

Comment: Note that `Main_Page`, with the default title capitalization setup, would refer to `Main Page`, not `Main page`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Title::newFromText`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classTitle.html#a38bc903dc6eb281b38a66029d7d62eb2) to create a new Title object representing the page. Once you have that, you can use [`Title::getPrefixedText`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classTitle.html#af5b1a7940de056155682dc7fd82a2ef1) to get the correct representation of the title meant for displaying it.